# Prove that the product is not an integer

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ a positive integer. Prove that the product
>   $$N = \frac{1}{p^{n^2}} \prod_{i=1;2 \nmid i}^{2n-1} \left[((p-1)i)! \binom{p^2 i}{pi}\right]$$
>   Is a positive integer that is not divisible by $p.$

How in the solution below did they get $v_p\binom{p^2i}{pi}=v_p((p^2i)!)-(v_p((pi)!)+v_p((p^2-p)i)!)$? Shouldn't it be $v_p\binom{p^2i}{pi}=v_p((p^2i)!)-(v_p((pi)!)-v_p((p^2-p)i)!)$? Also how does the rest of the argument work and is it correct?

**Book's solution:**

We define $v_p(x)$ such that if $v_p(x) = n$, then $p^n \mid x$ but $p^{n+1} \nmid x$. Now let $$a_i=\left[((p-1)i)! \binom{p^2 i}{pi}\right].$$ Now $v_p\binom{p^2i}{pi}=v_p((p^2i)!)-(v_p((pi)!)+v_p((p^2-p)i)!)$

also, $v_p(p^2i)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac {p^2i}{p^r}\rfloor=pi+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\lfloor \frac {pi}{p^r}\rfloor=pi+v_p(pi)$

also,$v_p((p^2-p)i))=(p-1)i+v_p((p-1)i)$ and so $v_p(a_i)=i$ and hence $v_p(\prod a_i)=n^2$.

Comment: "Shouldn't it be....?" Yes. Two negative signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without typo's. Let $a_i=((p-1)i)! \binom{p^2 i}{pi}$. We want to evaluate
$$v_p\left(\frac{1}{p^{n^2}} \prod_{i=1\text{, i odd.}}^{2n-1} a_i\right)$$

Note that by the identities

$$v_p\left(\binom{p^2i}{pi}\right)=v_p((p^2i)!)-v_p((pi)!)-v_p(((p^2-p)i)!)$$
$$v_p(p^2i)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac {p^2i}{p^r}\rfloor=pi+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\lfloor \frac {pi}{p^r}\rfloor=pi+v_p((pi)!)$$
$$v_p(((p^2-p)i)!)=(p-1)i+v_p(((p-1)i)!)$$

we have that $$v_p(a_i)=v_p(((p-1)i)!)+v_p\left(\binom{p^2i}{pi}\right)=v_p(((p-1)i)!)+pi-v_p(((p^2-p)i)!)=i$$ and hence $v_p(\prod a_i)=\sum v_p(a_i)=1+3+\dots+(2n-1)=n^2$.

Comment: How is $$v_p\left[\binom{p^2i}{pi}\right] = pi+v_p(pi)-v_p[(pi)!]-(p-1)i-v_p[(p-1)i] = i?$$

Comment: that is is not what I wrote. First, there is no $v_p(pi)$ term. second - note the differences between $v_p(((p-1)i)!)$ an $v_p(((p^2-p)i)!)$.